# hamburger icon reseting scroll position on the page

Tags: html, css

I copy pasted a hamburger icon for my web project, but for some reason when I click the icon it scrolls back to the top. I tried to change the margin and padding, but the result is always the same. I also tried to remove the animation part of the hamburger, still scrolls back up. Any thing wrong?

btw here is the link of the hamburger icon, the one I use is the first one. 
https://codepen.io/rosalieelphick/pen/xJyRoK

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" class="checkbox1 visuallyHidden" onclick="betterwork()">
        <label for="checkbox1" id="label">
          <div class="hamburger hamburger1">
            <span class="bar bar1"></span>
            <span class="bar bar2"></span>
            <span class="bar bar3"></span>
            <span class="bar bar4"></span>
          </div>
        </label>
```

**CSS**

```
.visuallyHidden {
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
    height: 1px; width: 1px;
    margin: -1px; padding: 0; border: 0;
}

#label {
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

.hamburger {
    margin: 0;
    margin-top: 20px;
    left: 20px;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 3;
}

.hamburger:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.hamburger .bar {
    padding: 0;
    width: 30px;
    height: 4px;
    background-color: maroon;
    display: block;
    border-radius: 4px;
    transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    position: absolute;
}

.bar1 {
    top: 0;
}

.bar2,
.bar3 {
    top: 13.5px;
}

.bar3 {
    right: 0;
}

.bar4 {
    bottom: 0;
}

.checkbox1:checked + label > .hamburger > .bar1{
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform-origin: 5%;
    
}

.checkbox1:checked + label > .hamburger > .bar2 {
    transform: translateX(-40px);
    background-color: transparent;
}

.checkbox1:checked + label > .hamburger > .bar3 {
    transform: translateX(40px);
    background-color: transparent;
}

.checkbox1:checked + label > .hamburger > .bar4 {
    transform-origin: 5%;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    width: 41px;
}
```

Comment: Nice animations you have there :)

Comment: Thanks! but I didn't made it... credits to Rosie Elphick! https://twitter.com/rosiecodes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hamburger menu you have picked uses a hidden checkbox to handle the toggle of the menu open and close. When you click the menu button, this checkbox is focused, and this focus causes a scroll to the top of the page.

The shortest answer is to add the following to your css:

```
.checkbox1 {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: So what should I do to change that?

Comment: I have edited the answer to solving your problem. If you've changed the class names, adding `display: none` to the checkbox should fix the problem.